# Custom profile properties

Tags: asp.net, profile

Following [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instructions I can define custom properties for a profile adding this to Web.Config:

```
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
    <providers>
      <add
        name="DefaultProfileProvider"
        type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        connectionStringName="MYCONEXION"
        applicationName="MyApp" />
    </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="IdRole" type="Integer" />
    <add name="IdUser" type="Integer" />
  </properties>
</profile>
```

The problem I find is, I can access this properties (`Profile.IdRole`) when block code is embeded in script, in a block `<script language="vb" runat="server">`.

When block code is in CodeBehind it looks like Profile is actually a different object/class. Also, if I move code from CodeBehind to embeded block, I have problems accesing some other classes and methods, for example `Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider` or a function from a module in my own project.

I guess I'm missing some prefix to `Profile.IdRole` when accessing it from CodeBehind, can you help?

**Error info:**

In CodeBehind, when I use `Profile.IdRole` I get error *IdRole is not member of Profile*.

If I use `HttpContext.Current.Profile.IdRole` I get *IdRole is not member of System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase*

When I use `Profile.IdRole` in embeded code and point the mouse over it, I get a tooltop: *Protected ReadOnly Property Profile as ProfileCommon*, now that I see that ReadOnly I'm not sure I followed the right documentation... Help?

Thank you

Comment: Try `HttpContext.Current.Profile`?

Comment: No, different error but also an error, I'll update question with this info

Comment: Are you using VB or C# in your code behind?

Answer (score 0):

The ProfileCommon class is a strongly typed class that inherits from ProfileBase. It is created at runtime and uses the custom property info defined in your web config file. Since it is created at runtime, it is not directly accessible from code-behind.

From code-behind, to access the current user's profile, use

```
HttpContext.Current.Profile
```

To access another user's profile, use

```
System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase.Create(username)
```

Both functions return an instance of the ProfileBase class.  Since it is not strongly typed using your custom properties, you have to use the `GetPropertyValue` and `SetPropertyValue` methods like so

```
Dim profile as ProfileBase = ProfileBase.Create("someuser")
profile.GetPropertyValue("IdRole")
profile.SetPropertyValue("IdRole", 42)
```